# Is it acceptable to load controllers in the route AND body?

Tags: angularjs

Most articles demonstrate one method or the other... specifying the controller in the route OR the body.  While I realize specifying the controller in the route provides additional benefits WHEN NEEDED (pre-loading required view resources, etc.), it is illogical to think that a modular application will be able to (or SHOULD) handle all of the functionality for a complex view.

Any proven examples (links) showing a combined approach would really help ease my mind.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You may use both, but not for the same instance of a controller.

As an example, you can use ng-controller for your page menu controller and define the page controller loaded into your ui-view in the state config. This is fine as long as the page view does not have an ng-controller the same controller.

Your controllers constructor will run twice if you invoke it twice.

**Added Snippet to Demonstrate**

So in the following code we bring in the controller IndexCtrl in the uiRouter state config and in the index.html view. As you can see if you run this snippet, you have two instances of the IndexCtrl running.

*Why is this a problem?*

It is not a problem if this is your intention. It becomes a problem if this is your intention, to have two instances of the controller. If you follow this pattern unknowingly and create an application you will have an unneeded instance of every controller.

This will also cause developer confusion. *How come I can't get back the value of a property in a controller?* You will see bugs like this because a developer will set a property on one instance of a controller and then expect the same value to be in the other instance.

Controllers are classes. They are constructor functions -- so you can have multiple instances of them. And there are valid use cases to have multiple instances of a controller. But you shouldn't accidentally have two instances.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {

      $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '*path',
        controller: "IndexCtrl as vm1",
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
      });


    }
  ])

.controller('IndexCtrl', IndexCtrl);


function IndexCtrl() {

  this.value = 0;

}
IndexCtrl.prototype.add = function() {
  this.value += 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="index.html">
    <div ng-controller="IndexCtrl as vm2">
      Controller1 {{vm1.value}} Controller2 {{vm2.value}}
      <button ng-click="vm1.add()">Add Ctrl1</button> 
      <button ng-click="vm2.add()">Add Ctrl2</button> 
    </div>
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... could you clarify?  You said, "no" but then mentioned that you CAN use both as long as your not using the same controller twice.  So, if the route specifies the template of "main" and controller of "mainCtrl", the page CAN specify a DIFFERENT controller (for example, "breadcrumCtrl") in the body.  Is this correct?

Comment: Gotcha.  Do you know of any blogs / sites / articles that demonstrate this combination?  I'm only finding one or the other.

Comment: You will find many questions on SO related to the bug instantiating a controller twice causes http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Angular+function+fires+twice